# Fresh .net web api solution return 401 for WeatherForecastController

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I installed a fresh .net core web api (5.0) with Identity Users (IdentityServer).
I added a middleware:

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private const string APIKEYNAME = "ApiKey";
    public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEYNAME, out var extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Api Key was not provided. (Using ApiKeyMiddleware) ");
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEYNAME);

        if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized client. (Using ApiKeyMiddleware)");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

and in my startup I added a middleware component:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Test002.Api", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test002.Api v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

When I open swagger configuration Im getting 401: Unauthorized.
What I'm missing?

here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LoVBH3Gc-60yQ4Titk5_WnCR6l5M-KHg/view?usp=sharing) to the solution on my gdrive.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the response StatusCode as 401 when the request header doesn't contain `ApiKey`, or it doesn't match that in appsettings.json. When you test with swagger, it won't add ApiKey in the request header.

Comment: How can I edit the swagger that when I call the api to actually add apiKey? I actually need bearer token to be passed to my api call and to get response from my api method